# Signal handling in C: program continues executing even after interruption

Tags: c, signal-handling

I do not understand why when I run this code and then use a control+C interrupt the program closes immediately but the log file shows "program ran successfully". How can I make it print the correct message?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile int globalFlag = 0;

void handler();

int main()
{
    FILE* log;
    log = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    while(globalFlag == 0){

        sleep(20);
        fprintf(log, "program ran successfully\n");
        fclose(log);

        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(log, "program shut by signal\n");
    fclose(log);
    return -1;

}

void handler()
{

    globalFlag = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely wanted the sleep statement to be outside of the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

static volatile int globalFlag = 0; 

void handler() { 
    globalFlag = 1; 
} 

int main() { 
    FILE* log; 
    log = fopen("log.txt", "a"); 
    signal(SIGINT, handler); 
    sleep(20); 

    if (globalFlag == 0){ 
        fprintf(log, "program ran successfully\n"); 
        fclose(log); 
        return 0; 
    } else { 
        fprintf(log, "program shut by signal\n"); 
        fclose(log); 
        return -1; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. It seems I had misunderstood what control+C does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite confused by 'It seems I had misunderstood what control+C does.' so let me have a longer take here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile int globalFlag = 0;
```

The type should be sig_atomic_t. The variable is already 0. Bad name.

```
void handler();
```

Handlers are supposed to accept an int. Bad name. Can be made static.

```
int main()
```

Should be 'void'.

```
{
    FILE* log;
    log = fopen("log.txt", "a");
```

Missing error checking.

```
signal(SIGINT, handler);
```

So here the handler is installed...

```
while(globalFlag == 0){
```

... the flag is immediately checked ...

```
    sleep(20);
    fprintf(log, "program ran successfully\n");
    fclose(log);
```

... and the program exits because you have not managed to send the signal fast enough.

```
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(log, "program shut by signal\n");
    fclose(log);
    return -1;

}
```

The issue would have been trivially debugged by running a simple thought experiment.